# angular2 - pipe - filter multiple json values

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have an array of nested json objects like this:

```
[{name: {en:'apple',it:'mela'}},{name:{en:'coffee',it:'caffè'}}]
```

I want to have a pipe which filters every object having values matching with a given argument.

On this purpose, I created a pipe which uses a  `Array.prototype.filter`  as following:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'search'
})    
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

        transform(items: any[], args: string): any {
           if(!args){
            return items;
           } else {
           return items.filter(item => item.name.en.toLowerCase().indexOf(args[0]) !== -1); //returns every name.en values matching with args

           }
        }   
    }
```

This allows me to filter by name.en.
How can I make it able to filter the values `name.en` and `name.it` too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OR operator when filtering.

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'search'
})    
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], args: string): any {
      if (!args){
        return items;
      } else {
        return items
          .filter(item => 
            item.name.en.toLowerCase().indexOf(args[0]) !== -1 || item.name.it.toLowerCase().indexOf(args[1]) !== -1 
          );
      }
    }   
}
```